# How to set up flask server startup?

Tags: linux, python, cron

I have a web-server that is based on flask+tornado combination. It works inside of a virtual environment (set up with python virtualenv).

I want the server to launch automatically on start up, from a regular user. What I have done to achieve this:

1) I have written a startup script with following contents:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/myserver
# enter virtualenv
source venv/bin/activate
# launch
python app.py > serverlog.log 2&>1 &
```

2) I have set up a crontab with `crontab -e` as:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
@reboot /home/ubuntu/start_service.sh
```

When I execute the startup script from the command line, everything is correctly launched. But after reboot in `serverlog.log` I see a stacktrace that tells of failure to bind to port 5000. what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Crontab is not smart enough to keep your server up. When it goes down, it has to wait till crontab runs again; your clients will get a 404 error from your faulty server.

I advise you to use something like [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). You can install it using easy_install like

```
   easy_install supervisor
```

You will need to deal with Supervisord and Supervisorctl. The first is a demon process manager that will run and make sure the PID from your

```
python app.py > serverlog.log 2&>1 &
```

keep running no matter what. You will be able to do such thing by creating a so called program on the supervisord.conf like

```
[program:flasktornado]
command=python app.py > serverlog.log 2&>1 &
```

Supervisorctl is how you control [ start | stop | restart ] the program you have just created on the supervisord configuration file. [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps) might help you.